# How are numbers in bit sequence being referred to?

Tags: instructions

For instance, the 0x123 value is stored to a register. What do the bits [7:3] mean for in the value? Are they talking about the binary value of 0x123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 0x123 is 123<sub>16</sub>, which is 291<sub>10</sub>, which is 000100100011<sub>2</sub>.

The most sensible way to number bits is giving the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) — Least Significant Bit — the bit position number of 0.  The next bit to the right gets 1 and so on.  This way each bit offers the opportunity to contribute 2<sup>N</sup> to the value of the number, where N is its bit position number.  If the bit is 1 it contributes that value, otherwise no contribution is made to the value.

*Base 10 works the same: a number like 405 decomposes as 4×10<sup>2</sup> + 0×10^<sup>1</sup> + 5×10<sup>0</sup>.*

*And to be clear in the old days some computers numbered bits in the other direction, which worked alright when only one size of item is considered, but modern computers now work with bytes, shorts, words, etc.., so keeping the LSB as bit position number 0 regardless of data size makes the most sense.*

```
  9876543210  bit position # (decimal numbers)
000100100011  binary digits
```

So this number is 2<sup>8</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>, which is 256 + 32 + 2 + 1 = 291<sub>10</sub>

Bits [7:3] are the *'ed ones:

```
    *****
  9876543210  bit position # (decimal numbers)
000100100011  binary digits
    *****
```

We might write that bits [7:3] of that number is 00100.

---

Let's say we have an 10-bit binary number, where we represent each digit with a letter.  So we have:

```
9876543210     bit position # (decimal numbers)
abcdefghij     binary number represeted by 8 variables (each is one bit)
0011110000     mask in your example (0xF0)
----------&    and operation
00cdef0000     result after and
---------->>4  shift operation
000000cdef     result after shift right by 4
```

This number, 000000cdef will be a number between 0 and 15<sub>10</sub>.

That sequence has "extracted" the 4-bit field as an unsigned number.

Remember also that in some cases, the 4-bit field [7:4] may not be the leftmost field: if the value were 16-bits, then there are 8 bits above 7.  The mask of 0xF0 will remove those upper 8 bits as well as clearing the lower 4 bits.  Turns out clearing the lower 4 bits isn't necessary there, since the shifting will do that on its own.

If the field you're interested in is leftmost or rightmost, fewer operations are necessary to extract it.

There are other sequences that can do the same extraction.  For one, we can shift first, then mask:

```
9876543210     bit position # (decimal numbers)
abcdefghij     binary number represeted by 8 variables (each is one bit)
---------->>4  shift operation
0000abcdef     result after shift right by 4
0000001111     mask (0xF: the one's need to move over compared to 0xF0)
----------&    mask operation
000000cdef     result after mask
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. Quick question let’s say I add 0x123 to a register and I use the ANDI operator with 0x123 and 0x0f0. And then I shift right logical 4 bits. It’s said to extract [7:4] bits from 0x123 how is that possible?

Comment: That combination of operations will isolate the field 4-bit and right justify it.  The isolation happens by using a mask of 0000 1111 0000, so keeping only the bits of interest.  The right justification happens with the shift.  The result is the value of those 4 bits as an unsigned number, so the result will be a value between 0 and 15.  See my edit above.

Comment: Crystal clear now thank you so much have an amazing day